# Using CGFloat.max to size label, moving it

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uilabel

I'm trying to make a label multilines, that fits the screen, so i'm using the CGFloat.max to make it's height dynamic... but using CGFloat.max is causing the label to ignore the positioning, any always keep on the position 0 in the Y axis....

Even passing any variable ou even a number to it, keeps on the 0 in Y axis

Any ideas to fix??

```
let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 50, screenWidthArea, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()

    self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: The wording of your question confused me. Are you trying to make a label the `width` and `height` of your screen?

Comment: I was trying to make the label fit to the text size in height, with the width of the screen. I've actually found the answer as you can see below

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've changed CGFloat.max to 0 and it worked well... Still no idea for the reason CGFloat.max locks the label on the top of screen.

`let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 50, screenWidthArea, 0))`